# Permission denied error in reading proc file

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, permission-denied

I was following a tutorial to learn kernel module programming. After that I wrote a little programming to do some process when /proc file is being read or write.I compiled the module successfully and did insmod too. But when ever I'm trying to read a proc file like

cat /proc/procfile

It throws permission denied error.

I included module permission function in my code and I found every time permission check is failed which actually throws me the error.

```
struct cred *proc_current; //to get the EUID for current task
static struct proc_dir_entry *our_proc_file;

static int module_permission(struct inode *inode, int op)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "permission is %d \n",op);
if(op==4||(op==2 && (proc_current->euid == 0)))
 return 0;
return -EACCES;
}

.....
//Init module
static int __init proc_init(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Init module loaded \n");
our_proc_file=create_proc_entry(PROC_NAME, 0644, NULL);
if(our_proc_file == NULL)
{
remove_proc_entry(PROC_NAME,proc_root);
printk(KERN_INFO "Error in creating proc file \n");
return -ENOMEM;
}
our_proc_file->proc_fops=&fops;
our_proc_file->proc_iops=&iops;
our_proc_file->mode=S_IFREG | S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR;
our_proc_file->uid=0;
our_proc_file->gid=0;
our_proc_file->size=80;
printk(KERN_INFO "proc file created in '/proc' \n");
return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the file permission to 777 in init module but that doesn't help me.
When I exclude the permission check function it works.
Also just have a look at the permission function, in which

```
printk(KERN_INFO "permission is %d \n",op);
```

always print 36. What is the reason for this and how to actually do the permission check here?

Actual code is here
[procfile.c](http://pastebin.com/2gp52rnn)

Comment: Please fix indention.

Comment: tutorial was based on 2.6 version and I corrected all the syntax according to the recent version

Answer (score 0):

Most of the files under /proc are root-only, if you try to read them as a regular user you'll get the result you cite.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`our_proc_file->mode=S_IFREG | S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR;`

With
`our_proc_file->mode = S_IRUGO | S_IWUGO | S_IXUGO;`

Reference:   [stat.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/stat.h)